# Force FireFox to reload print CSS

Tags: firefox, printing, css

I'm currently tweaking the CSS layout for the *printed* version of my Blog. A huge problem with that is: FireFox caches the print CSS (the one with `media="print"`) and does not reload it, so changes to it are not visible.

The usual CTRL+F5 does not work in the print-preview page and I don't want to clear the whole browser cache every time I updated my print CSS.

Any way to quickly see the changes to the print-CSS file?

Comment: Firefox extention to reload just the css.. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-reloader/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox extention to reload just the css.. 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-reloader/

Answer (score 4):

Try to press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Mac.
It will reload page, overriding the cache.
This is sometimes called a “forced reload”.

See: [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation)

---

> According the letter of the HTTP caching specification, user agents
>   should never cache URLs with query strings. While Internet Explorer
>   and Firefox ignore this, Opera and Safari don’t

Troubleshooting:

- Try to go to the CSS link directly and refresh it from there by using above key shortcuts.
- Type `about:config` into the URL bar then find the entry titled `network.http.use-cache`. Set this to `false`.
- You may also try to add at the end of the CSS URL question mark with something like '?a' or something else, browser will "think" it's a dynamic page and it'll force to reload it.

  E.g.:

  If you've access to the html, add question mark at then end of a URL.

  If you don't, try the following cache trick and check if that works:

  Load the main page at `http://example.com/` which loads cached CSS file at `http://example.com/print.css`, so you can directly go to `http://example.com/print.css?nocache` by adding `?nocache` at the end. Most of the web browsers should ignore their caches for any files which has question mark in the URL. Then try to reload the main page at `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/?nocache`

  Also check: [What does the question mark at then end of a css include url do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634123/what-does-the-question-mark-at-then-end-of-a-css-include-url-do) and [Is it the filename or the whole URL used as a key in browser caches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83990/is-it-the-filename-or-the-whole-url-used-as-a-key-in-browser-caches)
- The last method (as OP already mentioned) is to clear the cache by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, depending on your system).
- Check: [Force browser to refresh css, javascript, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474345/force-browser-to-refresh-css-javascript-etc)

Comment: On the current Firefox (26.0), Shift-F5 brings up the Profiler panel of the Web Developer tools, and Ctrl-Shift-F5 does nothing.

Comment: Try: Ctrl+Shift+R instead.

Comment: Crtl+Shift+R does not work in current version of Firefox (31.0) either. The only "native" solutions are to clear the cache in the Options->Advanced->Network configuration, or disable caching completetly in about:config->network.http.use-cache. Your other tricks do work as well.

Comment: Alternative to Ctrl+Shift+R is Ctrl+F5, but double check, maybe you have some key shortcut conflicts.

Comment: On a Mac, Command+Shift+R still works for me in Firefox 31. For Windows, [both Ctrl+F5 and Ctrl+Shift+R are still listed too](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_navigation), @Chris.

Comment: *"You may also try to add at the end of the CSS URL question mark with something like '?a'"*, but then such needs to be done in the HTML that loads the CSS, and the "?a" needs to change for each request. Doing this when loading the CSS directly will still make the page use the original URL.

Comment: Example: example.com/ loads example.com/print.css which is cached, then you go directly to example.com/print.css?nocache. So web browser cache should ignore any files with added question mark at the end of the URI.

Comment: ...but no page will use `example.com/print.css?nocache` unless its HTML refers to that. If a page loads `example.com/print.css` and you just open a new tab to fetch `example.com/print.css?nocache` or `example.com/print.css?xyz=123` and then reload the first tab, then the first tab will still use the (cached) version for `example.com/print.css`, not what was received using `example.com/print.css?nocache`. (Even if the contents are the same, a browser will consider the two URLs to be different.)

Comment: If you reload `example.com/print.css?nocache`, then web browser should refresh its cached version of that file. So reloading `example.com/` again it should use the refreshed version of previously cached file (included in HTML). I think web browser should know that this is the same file, because this method worked for me couple of times (unless there is some other caching engine in the middle such as varnishd or reverse-proxies). Page didn't work, unless I've reloaded the specific CSS file. Some CMSes (e.g. Drupal) using this cache trick to force web browser to reload their caching.

Comment: *"If you reload example.com/print.css?nocache, then web browser should refresh its cached version of that file."*, yes *that* file, that is: the file with URL `print.css?nocache`. So, *"So reloading example.com/ again it should use the refreshed version of previously cached file (included in HTML)"* is false. (Compare to loading `user?id=5` vs `user?id=6`. The internet would break if those would be shared.)

Comment: It's difficult to test unless you've already tested it that this doesn't work. `user?id=5` and `user?id=6` points the same path (or file), but it has different query string (different input variables), so how browser cache threats them depending on the implementation of cache strategy for urls with different params. If you think that this method won't work, I could remove it. Check also: [Is it the filename or the whole URL used as a key in browser caches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83990/is-it-the-filename-or-the-whole-url-used-as-a-key-in-browser-caches).

Comment: I feel *"user agents should never cache URLs with query strings"* is a false [summary of](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.9) *"since some applications have traditionally used GETs and HEADs with query URLs [...] to perform operations with significant side effects, caches MUST NOT treat responses to such URIs as fresh **unless the server provides an explicit expiration time**"* (emphasis mine). If (sane) browsers would not cache any URL that has a query string, then you'd see your browser fetch the CSS and images for *every* page you visit here on Stack Exchange...